# Converting well number to the identifier on a 96 well plate

Tags: python, bioinformatics

In a 96 well plate there are 8 columns (A,B,...) and 12 rows (01 ... 12);
so the plate looks like this:

```
A01 A02 ... A12
B01 B02 ... B12
C01 ...
...
H01 ..
```

Currently I have identified the plates as:

```
 1 2 3 4 ... 12
 13 14 15 ...24
 ..
 84 ...      96
```

How can I write a function `wellnumber2wellidentifier` to convert the numerical index into the format used on the top? For example, well `1` would return `A01` and well `13` would return `B01`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh sure, go and make it 1-based why don't you...

```
'ABCDEFGH'[(num - 1) // 12] + '%02d' % ((num - 1) % 12 + 1,)
```

Comment: +1, just for the sigh `Oh sure, go and make it 1-based why don't you`

Comment: and vertically in case you end up here like me:
'ABCDEFGH'[(num-1) % 8] + '%02d' % ((num - 1) // 8 + 1,)

Answer (score 1):

Taking @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams 's answer a few steps further. . .here are two methods that:

1. Work for nearly any sized rack (rows X cols)
2. Convert to and from numeric position from an A1, B1, etc style well position.

`@staticmethod
def convertNumericWellPosToA1Style(numericPos, contRows, contCols, colOrRowMajor, padWithZeros):
    """
    Convert a numeric position to an A1 style position.
    Parameters
    ----------
    numericPos : int
        Numeric well position to be converted.
    contMaxRows : int
        Max number of container rows.
    contMaxCols : int
        Max number of container cols.
    colOrRowMajor : str
        'col' or 'row' for column or row major addressing.
    padWithZeros : bool
        Whether to pad the numeric portion returned, with zeros or not.
        i.e., A1 or A01
    """
    if numericPos < 1:
        raise ValueError("Container position value '" + str(numericPos) + "' must be 1 or greater.")
    if contCols < 1:
        raise ValueError("Container columns value '" + str(contCols) + "' must be 1 or greater.")
    if contRows < 1:
        raise ValueError("Container rows value '" + str(contRows) + "' must be 1 or greater.")
    if numericPos > contCols * contRows:
        raise ValueError("Container position value '" + str(numericPos) + "' exceeds the maximum container wells possible of '" + str(contCols * contRows) + "'.")
    if colOrRowMajor == "row":
        if padWithZeros:
            return 'ABCDEFGH'[(numericPos - 1) // contCols] + '%02d' % ((numericPos - 1) % contCols + 1,)
        else:
            return 'ABCDEFGH'[(numericPos - 1) // contCols] + str((numericPos - 1) % contCols + 1)
    elif colOrRowMajor == "col":
        if padWithZeros:
            return 'ABCDEFGH'[(numericPos - 1) % contRows] + '%02d' % (math.ceil(numericPos / contRows),)
        else:
            return 'ABCDEFGH'[(numericPos - 1) % contRows] + str(math.ceil(numericPos / contRows))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Container traversal value '" + colOrRowMajor + "' must be 'col' or 'row'.")`

@staticmethod
def ConvertA1StylePositionToNumeric(A1StylePos : str, contRows : int, contCols : int, colOrRowMajor : str):
    #Check for at least two chars
    if len(A1StylePos) == 0:
        raise ValueError("An empty A1 style well position can't be converted.")
    if len(A1StylePos) == 1:
        raise ValueError("At least 2 characters are required in an A1 style well position.")
    #make upper case
    A1StylePos = A1StylePos.upper()
    colPart = 0
    #get parts of the A1 style rack position
    rowPart = A1StylePos.upper()[0:1]
    if ord(rowPart) < 65 or ord(rowPart) > 90:
        raise ValueError("The first character of the A1 style well position must be a letter A - Z.")
    colPartAsString = A1StylePos[1:len(A1StylePos)]
    if colPartAsString.isdigit():
        colPart = int(colPartAsString)
    else:
        raise ValueError("The characters after the first character of the well position must be numeric.")
    #error checking
    if ord(A1StylePos[0]) < 65 or ord(A1StylePos[0]) > 90:
        raise ValueError("The first character of the well position '" + A1StylePos + "' must be a character A through Z.")
    if contCols < 1:
        raise ValueError("Container columns value '" + str(contCols) + "' must be 1 or greater.")
    if contRows < 1:
        raise ValueError("Container rows value '" + str(contRows) + "' must be 1 or greater.")
    if contRows > 26:
        raise ValueError("Container rows value '" + str(contRows) + "' must not be greater than 26.")
    if colPart > contCols:
        raise ValueError("Well position value '" + A1StylePos + "' exceeds the maximum container columns possible of '" + str(contCols) + "'.")
    if colPart < 1:
        raise ValueError("Well position value '" + A1StylePos + "' must be 1 or greater.")
    if (ord(rowPart) - 64) > contRows:
        raise ValueError("Well position value '" + A1StylePos + "' refers to a well that exceeds the maximum container columns possible of '" + str(contCols) + "'.")
    #convert 
    if colOrRowMajor == "col":
      return (int)(((colPart - 1) * contRows) + (ord(rowPart) - 64))
    elif colOrRowMajor == "row":
      return  (int)(((ord(rowPart) - 65) * contCols) + colPart);
    else:
        raise ValueError("Container traversal value '" + colOrRowMajor + "' must be 'col' or 'row'.")